# Easy way to view multiple Y variables against same X

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to visualize many time series at once. I am new at R, and have spent about 6 hours searching the web and reading about how to tackle this relatively simple problem. My dataset has five time points arranged as rows, and 100 columns. I can easily plot any column against the time points with `qplot(time, var2, geom="line")`. But I want to learn how to do this for a flexible number of columns, and how to print 6 to 12 of the individual graphs on one page.

Here I learned about the multiplot function, got that to work in terms of layout.

What I am stuck on is how for get the list of variables into a FOR statement so I can have one statement to plot all the variables against the same five time points.

this is what I am playing with. It makes 9 plots, 3 columns wide, but I do not know how to get all my variables into the array for yvars?

```
for (i in 1:9) {
         p1 = qplot(symbol,yvar, geom ="smooth", main = i))
         plots[[i]] <- p1  # add each plot into plot list
     }
multiplot(plotlist = plots, cols = 3)
```

Stupidly on my part right now it makes 9 identical plots. So how do I create the list so the above will cycle through all my columns and make those plots?

Answer (score 1):

first melt all your data using the reshape2 package

`datm <- melt(your.original.data.frame, id = "time")`

Now plot it using facets:

`qplot(time, value, data = datm, facets= variable ~ ., geom="point")`

Let me know if this works. If you could, please upload your data, it would help tremendously.

Comment: note that you need the `ggplot2` package loaded for this solution as well.

Comment: @ChelseaE. I think I may need to reformat my data to make you command work. Here are first three of 2600 lines: 
gene 0 1 2 3 4

7892502 4.62 4.50 4.02 4.06 4.59

7892507 4.31 4.71 4.46 4.07 4.25

7892568 10.39 10.20 10.60 10.64 10.35

So for 7892502 I want plot of those 5 numbers against 0,1,2,3,4.

Then for 7892507, same for the numbers on that row agains 0,1,2,3,4

And so on.

Do I need to reformat the data, and if so, any hints where can I read about how to do that in R instead of copying and pasting in Excel?

Thanks, Rob

Comment: @user2714356, please save your data frame to a CSV file and upload it to this [link](http://bit.ly/16RSIl0).

To do this adapt this command to your data and output directory: `write.table(mydata, "c:/mydata.txt", sep=",")`